# What UI front-end framework should i use with Angular 2

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-material, angular2-template

I'm looking for recommendations on what front end framework should i use when developing an angular 2 single page app. I'm looking into Material design 2 but as it's still in alpha it seems to be missing a lot of the layout and responsive features i need. I've looked at using material design lite but i'm reading it doesn't work well with dynamically routed pages the same with bootstrap - has anybody used these successfully? What's everybody using?

Comment: Bootstrap widgets done by the angular-ui team are getting _very_ solid: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io  - APIs are there and development progressing rapidly. This is currently the only library that features native, fully functional date picker, modal service etc.

Comment: `What's everybody using?`, different things

Comment: Checkout PrimeNG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular2 material would probably publish a beta version by the end of the year.
A good candidate for meantime is [ng2-material](https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material).
More UI elements are available from [primeNG](http://builtwithangular2.com/primeng-rich-ui-components/) and [Vaadin Elements](https://vaadin.com/elements)

Comment: [downvote reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an UI library created using the latest and greatest Angular 8 with the awesome CDK please check out [lego](https://github.com/vjai/lego). The library has fair set of components and also provides simple abstractions for extending and creating custom components. You can checkout the documentation [here](https://vjai.github.io/lego).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [lego](https://github.com/vjai/lego).